# How to pass runtime information to Tensorflow 2 graph functions?

Tags: tensorflow

I have 2 functions which require runtime knowledge:

1. global whitening, i.e. subtracting the global dataset mean and dividing by the global dataset std. For the training data, I do it only after augmentations, so it can't be done before entering the graph.
2. augment the training data with random partial occlusions - I need the training shape to know what sizes and which offsets are allowed for the occlusions.

When I try something like

```
num_classes = gt.shape[2]

class Consts:
  mean = None
  std = None
  n_classes = None

CONSTS = Consts()

@tf.function
def create_dataset(img_part, gt, mean, std):
  if CONSTS.mean is None:
    CONSTS.mean = tf.Variable(mean, dtype=tf.float32)
  if CONSTS.std is None:
    CONSTS.std = tf.Variable(std, dtype=tf.float32)
  if CONSTS.n_classes is None:
    CONSTS.n_classes = tf.constant(gt.shape[2])
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.concat((img_part, gt), axis=2)).cache().map(crop_and_normalize).batch(10).repeat()

@tf.function
def crop_and_normalize(data):
  data = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(tf.image.random_crop(data, (8, 8, 3 + CONSTS.n_classes)))
  return ((data[:, :, :3] - CONSTS.mean) / (CONSTS.std + tf.keras.backend.epsilon()), data[:, :, 3:])

data = create_dataset(img_part, gt, tf.reduce_mean(big_img, axis=(0, 1)), tf.math.reduce_std(big_img, axis=(0, 1)))
```

The last line triggers the following:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-9b521e60e99e> in <module>()
----> 1 data = create_dataset(img_part, gt, tf.reduce_mean(big_img, axis=(0, 1)), tf.math.reduce_std(big_img, axis=(0, 1)))

7 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: Const:0
```

This is a simplified version without the augmentation yet, but I guess I'll run into the same problem when trying the occlusions.

Any ideas how one can overcome this? Do I have to run in eager mode and forgo the performance benefits of tf.function?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem which does not involve using graph variables. The global graph variable approach is deprecated, the way to pass runtime information to the graph is through the dataset.

One simply needs to create tensor datasets comprised from just a single tensor with `from_tensors` containing the runtime information (it could be combined to a single parameter vector, or each runtime variable could be represented by a different dataset).

After creating these datasets, they need to be combined using `Dataset.zip`, then every map could pass it on to the next map, and all the functions in the pipeline would get these parameters passed to them as their arguments.